# dealing with colours in d3.js's chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, gradient, chord-diagram

I found this excellent example of a chord diagram visualizing Über rides: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/

Here's the code that is uses (fully available here: https://github.com/sghall/d3-chord-diagrams):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      #tooltip {
        color: white;
        opacity: .5;
        background: #333;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 10px solid lightgrey;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        visibility: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        pointer-events: none;
      }
      #circle circle {
        fill: none;
        pointer-events: all;
      }
      path.group {
        fill-opacity: .;
      }
      path.chord {
        fill-opacity: .65;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: .00000025px;
      }
      #circle:hover path.fade {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <script src="lib/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/queue.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mapper.js"></script>
    <script>
      //*******************************************************************
      //  CREATE MATRIX AND MAP
      //*******************************************************************
      queue()
        .defer(d3.json, 'data/EP-matrix.json')
        .defer(d3.csv, 'data/EP-cities.csv')
        .await(function(err, matrix, mmap) { 
          if (err) console.log(err);
          _.each(mmap, function (d, i) { d.id=i; d.data=d.color })
          drawChords(matrix, mmap);
        });
      //*******************************************************************
      //  DRAW THE CHORD DIAGRAM
      //*******************************************************************
      function drawChords (matrix, mmap) {
        var w = 1300, h = 1300, r1 = h / 2, r0 = r1 - 110;

        var chord = d3.layout.chord()
            .padding(.02)
            .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)
            .sortChords(d3.descending);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r0)
            .outerRadius(r0 + 20);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
          .append("svg:g")
            .attr("id", "circle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

            svg.append("circle")
                .attr("r", r0 + 20);

        var rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);
        chord.matrix(matrix);

        var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
            .data(chord.groups())
          .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "group")
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

        g.append("svg:path")
            .style("stroke", "grey")
            .style("fill", function(d) { return rdr(d).gdata; })
            .attr("d", arc);

        g.append("svg:text")
            .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("font-family", "helvetica, arial, sans-serif")
            .style("font-size", "9px")
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
                  + "translate(" + (r0 + 26) + ")"
                  + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
            })
            .text(function(d) { return rdr(d).gname; });

          var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
                .data(chord.chords())
              .enter().append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", "chord")
                .style("stroke", "grey")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return _.where(mmap, {id: d.source.index })[0].data;; })
                .attr("d", d3.svg.chord().radius(r0))
                .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                  d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .style("visibility", "visible")
                    .html(chordTip(rdr(d)))
                    .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 100)+"px"})
                    .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 100)+"px";})
                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) { d3.select("#tooltip").style("visibility", "hidden") });

          function chordTip (d) {
            var p = d3.format(".1%"), q = d3.format(",.2r")
            return "Chord Info:<br/>"
              +  d.sname + " → " + d.tname
              + ": " + p(d.svalue) + "<br/>"
              + d.tname + " → " + d.sname
              + ": " + p(d.tvalue) + "<br/>";
          }

          function groupTip (d) {
            var p = d3.format(".1%"), q = d3.format(",.2r")
            return "Group Info:<br/>"
                + d.gname + " : " + p(d.gvalue) + "<br/>";
            }

          function mouseover(d, i) {
            d3.select("#tooltip")
              .style("visibility", "visible")
              .html(groupTip(rdr(d)))
              .style("top", function () { return (d3.event.pageY - 80)+"px"})
              .style("left", function () { return (d3.event.pageX - 130)+"px";})

            chordPaths.classed("fade", function(p) {
              return p.source.index != i
                  && p.target.index != i;
            });
          }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what it displays:

[image]

Now, this represents a directed graph, where the colour of any given chord reflects the origin colour of the edge.

What if I wanted to display undirected data? Would there be a way to either mix the two colours from origin and destination? Or better yet, to linearly fade the chord colour from the origin to the destination?

Comment: Yes, both of those are possible. You probably want a [gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) for the latter.

Comment: Very good news! Do you have an idea how to go about implementing a gradient in the code above? I'm guessing I should change ".style("fill", function(d) { return rdr(d).gdata; })" but'Im not too sure how to proceed...

Comment: Sorry, I meant: ".style("fill", function(d) { return _.where(mmap, {id: d.source.index })[0].data;; })"

Comment: You'd need to define the gradient and then reference it in the fill, see e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421

Comment: This is getting me closer, but my skills in js don't cut it. Would you have time to orient me on how to do this in the above code? I'd be thankful, to say the least, but I'd understand if you didn't have time. Your links are great already. Cheers!

Comment: Well I would, for each of the chords, create a gradient definition in the `defs` section of the SVG. Give that an ID that you can derive directly from the data, e.g. the index and a prefix. Then all you need to do is reference this identifier (using the same ID) when you're setting the `fill`.

Comment: Alright, I'm stuck... With the information you gave me, I might ask another question more specifically about how to actually code this... Thanks!